# Why does the jquery validation on step require the value to be a multiple of the step?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using a numeric input with step=5 and min=13 and max=102. The jquery validation plugin is triggered because the input value is not a multiple of the step. I don't understand why it would be programmed like this.

[image]

I've tried using both a numeric input as well as a range input and they both use the same underlying logic for step with the jquery validate plugin.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="range" asp-for="AgeRangeMax" min="17" max="102" step="5" class="custom-range">
    <Label id="AgeRangeMaxDisplay">@Model.AgeRangeMax</Label>
 </div>
 <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display:block;">
    <span asp-validation-for="AgeRangeMax"></span>
 </div>
```

I'm using jquery validate and the unobtrusive plugins. THis is an asp.net core web app although I don't believe that's relevant for the issue I am struggling with.

```
<script src="~/libman/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/libman/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/libman/jquery-validate-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I would like for the step validation to work where it insures the number is a step of 5 starting with 17, so valid values are 17, 22, 27, 32, etc. I am really surprised that this is not working out of the box.

Comment: *"I am really surprised that this is not working out of the box"* ~ Looks like you need to notify the developer about this on [his GitHub page](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation).  SO is not for complaining about bugs when there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @Sparky, I wanted to make sure that there is not some aspect of this I am missing.